# What is the income by profession and social class?

Tags: downtime, runequest-6

On pages 81–83 of *RuneQuest 6* the social class and profession of a character are referenced several times as determining base downtime income. There is a Social Class table mentioned as well. But no matter how many times I comb over the Economics & Equipment chapter, the Careers and Development chapter, or the section on social class in the Culture & Community chapter, I can't make sense of downtime income or find this table it mentions. "Income" is listed in the index, but only points me back to these same few pages.

Take the example of the baker, provided in the text. It says that a freeman baker "might expect to earn 30 SP in a week". But where does this number come from? It doesn't correspond to anything in the text that I can find; nor to any numbers in the Civilized Social Class table (p. 32) or Minimum Maintenance Costs table (p. 82). It doesn't seem to be derived from the selling price of goods (which would be awkward, but at least an answer), as there is no listed price for bread by the loaf.

How is income determined?

Comment: I distinctly remember said chart but I don't have a rulebook. It's possible it was only in an earlier version like RQ3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Maintenance Costs table *is* what is being referred to, and it's modern ideas of how pay and profit work that make what the section is saying so hard to grasp. Designer Lawrence "Loz" Whitaker [explains the disconnect on the publisher's forum](http://designmechanism.freeforums.org/where-is-the-income-chart-t265.html#p6123):

> In the ancient/classical world, and right up until the late feudal era, what you earned was governed largely by your social class, rather than whether you were a gem cutter or a baker. Remember that disposable income was not the same as earned income: a gem cutter might be selling cut stones at high prices, but his operating costs will also be substantial and the number of units he sells will be low when compared with his pal the baker. Jack the Gem Cutter and Bob the Baker might have disposable incomes of roughly the same level, although the materials they deal in are vastly different in value. Also bear in mind the nature of commerce: haggling is very common, which shaves-away margin. The wealthy don't expect to pay the highest prices, even for luxury goods — and many sellers of luxury goods made a loss where wealthy customers were concerned just to gain reputation and a reasonable customer base.

And then puts a very clear, fine point on it in the next paragraph:

> The minimum Maintenance Costs on page 82 give you a good idea of the kinds of income, based on Social Class, you can expect to earn if you are a) competent at your job; b) have the custom and patronage. Most trades can expect to make their daily/weekly/annual Maintenance requirement: so a Freeman, which would encompass most artisans, can expect to make at least 2 SP per day, 15 per week and 750 per year. As GM, adjust this up or down depending on whether trade is good, customers are generous, the region is prosperous, or if conditions are dreadful: see the Seasonal Income table on page 83.

So, effectively, your maintenance costs *are* your typical income, because working just to sustain your current quality of living was the historical norm that RuneQuest 6 is modelling. (Actually, phrased that way, that's not really any different from the typical modern person's situation.) Money is not normal and trade for goods and services in-kind is the norm, and so your income does not typically result in profit beyond your expenses, as we understand "profit" with our modern financial-theory conditioning.

The long and short of it then, is that reading the daily cost of living right off the table on page 82 is how a character's basic income is determined.

Comment: This was one of the more frequently asked questions about this edition of RQ, so it's good to see this here.